# I do not know what's wrong with my database. Displays errors

Tags: sql-server, database

I created two tables. And I need to have two Ids in the second table of `Friends`. `UserId` is Id from the `UserInformation` table. `FriendId` is Id already in this table. I need to make a relationship between these two tables and correctly make FK and PK. I tried to do it myself but it screams what I did not do right here - REFERENCES [UserInformation] (UserId)

I need your help to do the job correctly

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInformation]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Login] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [Password] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [FirstName] [NCHAR](10) NOT NULL,
    [LastName] [NCHAR](10) NOT NULL,
    [Email] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL,
    [RegistrationDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [Groups] [VARCHAR](50) NOT NULL
)
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Friends]
(
    [UserId] [INT] NOT NULL,
    [FriendId] [INT]  NOT NULL,

    PRIMARY KEY (FriendId),
    CONSTRAINT FK_UserInformationFriend 
        FOREIGN KEY (UserId) REFERENCES [UserInformation](UserId)
) 
GO

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserInformation] 
    ADD CONSTRAINT [DF_UserInformation_RegistrationDate]  
        DEFAULT (GETDATE()) FOR [RegistrationDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE UserInformation
    ADD CONSTRAINT DF_UserInformation_Login_Unique UNIQUE(Login)
GO

ALTER TABLE UserInformation
   ADD CONSTRAINT DF_UserInformation_Email_Unique UNIQUE(Email)
GO

ALTER TABLE UserInformation
   ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInformation] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
GO

ALTER TABLE Friends
    ADD CONSTRAINT [PK_Friends] PRIMARY KEY ([UserId])
GO
```

Comment: Don't just say it displays errors.. _post the error_

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid error - foreign key 'FK_UserInformationFriend' references invalid column userId in referenced table userInformation

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid How do I properly write FK and PK in this case?

Comment: i think you should set id column as primary key in UserInformation and then set it as FK in other table it will work.

Comment: @UsmanMirza 
Can write if it is not difficult how it will look in the code? and then in two of the two Ids, and I'm doing it in the same way and do as you say. but how you see is not coming out

Comment: @VovaMakarovych check below my answer, run one by one command it will work,. if it helps accept the answer.

Comment: "Displays errors" is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First Change it as:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[UserInformation](
[Id] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
[Login] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[Password] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[FirstName] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
 [LastName] [nchar](10) NOT NULL,
[Email] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
[RegistrationDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
[Groups] [varchar](50) NOT NULL
)
```

then:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Friends](
[UserId] [int] NOT NULL,
[FriendId] [int]  NOT NULL,
PRIMARY KEY (FriendId),
  CONSTRAINT FK_UserInformationFriend FOREIGN KEY (UserId)
  REFERENCES [UserInformation](Id)
   )
```

and Last:

```
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[UserInformation] 
ADD  CONSTRAINT [DF_UserInformation_RegistrationDate]  DEFAULT 
(getdate()) FOR [RegistrationDate]
GO

ALTER TABLE UserInformation
ADD  CONSTRAINT DF_UserInformation_Login_Unique  UNIQUE (Login)
GO

 ALTER TABLE UserInformation
 ADD  CONSTRAINT DF_UserInformation_Email_Unique  UNIQUE (Email)
```

No need these as primary is already set for both tables:

```
ALTER TABLE UserInformation
 ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_UserInformation] PRIMARY KEY ([Id])
 GO

ALTER TABLE Friends
ADD  CONSTRAINT [PK_Friends]  PRIMARY KEY ([UserId])
GO
```

Note: if you need multiple primary keys then go for composite primarys:

```
primary key (FriendId, UserId)
```

Comment: Pk do not need to be specified?